# CSS: transform 1 pixel shift on Chrome

Tags: html, css

In the actual version of the Chrome browser there is a little issue when transition of this code finishes: 1 pixel shift of the line height on the bottom (on hover of the links).

Also, I've noticed that in code snippets of jsfiddle and here it may not be visible, but on the CodePen and **on my website** this is what happens. Checked on Firefox - everything is fine and on every web site.

Here is snippet of Stack Overflow and CodePen:

https://codepen.io/Maxim222/pen/OQWWEB

```css
body{
  background:#111;
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
ul li{
   float:left;
   position:relative;
    
  }
li a{
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
    
 li a:before{
      content:'';
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      background-color: #fb0;
      bottom: 0px;
      height: 15px;
      left: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      transition:all 1s;
}
li a:hover:before{
      bottom:0;
      transform: scaleX(1);
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Worldsdfsdf</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, it's not your fault, it's a "glitch" with the scaleX param. If you use 0.99 as a value instead of 1, it should work fine.

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  background-color: #fb0;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
ul li a:hover:before {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0.99);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.99);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Worldsdfsdf</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a good way, I've tried it. But is there clean way of doing it without 0.99 ? :))

Comment: as I said, it's a bug, so I'm pretty sure there is no way to fix/hack this. I may be wrong.

Comment: Hmmm ok, I guess nobody cares anymore xD your answer will be accepted

Comment: to be fair I don't use scaleXY anymore ^^ I don't like it

Comment: Hmm I don't like it either, but what could replace it as an alternative?

Comment: Javascript... Always Javascript :p I know it's tempting to do all these stuff with the great css3 (I'm the first to do it haha) but if css3 fail at something, use the mighty js ;) And if you REALLY want to do it in css, juste animate left pos and width, you'll get the very same result. place the rectangle at 50% left, go to 0 and 100% width